# Backbone: how the trigger function works

Tags: events, backbone.js, callback

I'm trying to learn Backbone by looking at an app that someone I know made together with the backbone documentation.  The app has a Bucket model and a Company model (i.e. you put companies in the bucket).  There's one thing in this bit that I'm unclear about, namely, how it uses the `trigger` method.

Backbone documentation has this to say about `trigger`:

#### trigger `object.trigger(event, [*args])`

> Trigger callbacks for the given event, or space-delimited list of events. Subsequent arguments to trigger will be passed along to the event callbacks.

In the code I'm looking at, `trigger` is called like this:

```
this.trigger("add:companies", Companies.get(companyId));
```

**Two questions:**

1. The `event` I assume is `add`ing a company, but at what point in the code below does that actually happen? Is it when `this.set({ "companies": arr }, { silent: true });` is run or when `this.save();` is run (or something else)?
2. If `Companies.get(companyId)` is the optional argument, what function is it actually passed to?

**Excerpt from original code**

```
window.Bucket = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: function() {
    return {
      companies: []
    };
  },

  addCompany: function(companyId) {
    var arr = this.get("companies");
    arr.push(companyId);
    this.set({ "companies": arr }, { silent: true });
    this.save();
    this.trigger("add:companies", Companies.get(companyId));
  },

  // ...
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `companies` property of the bucket is being updated in the `addCompany` method you describe. An annotated version of your example shows what's taking place:

```
  // 1. get array of companies currently included in the bucket:
  var arr = this.get("companies");

  // 2. add a company to the array
  arr.push(companyId);

  // 3. replace the bucket's company list with the array,
  //    suppressing validation and events:
  this.set({"companies": arr}, {silent: true});

  // 4. save the bucket:
  this.save();
```

`trigger` isn't actually affecting the model--it's just a way of letting other pieces of the application know that the company has been added. You could turn around and catch it somewhere else using [`on`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Events-on) with the bucket model:

```
var bucket = new window.Bucket();

// do stuff

bucket.on('add:companies', function(company) {
  alert('a new company has been added to the bucket.');
});
```

Comment: ok thanks, but can you confirm that Companies.get(companyId) is still being passed as an argument to some function (as the documentation would suggest)

Comment: That's just retrieving the company model in question and passing it to the callback. The anonymous handler I attached to the `bucket.on` listener in my example will receive the same model as its `company` argument.

Comment: but that's the thing. I don't know what the callback is that the company model is being passed to...it doesn't indicate it in the function addCompany

Comment: There aren't any callbacks bound to that event in your question. Your best bet is probably to search the code for `add:companies` (the name of the event) and try to find any listeners assigned to it using `.on`. Depending how the code is structured, there could even be more than one...